# Store values of multiple API calls on same state variable on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, themoviedb-api

I want to call two different api and store it in the same state variable using setState. And then I will be rendering the state data into a flat list. I am using themoviedb api, if that makes a difference. For example, please take a look at the code below:

NOTE: I don't want to override the first api call data with second, instead I want to append the result from second api call to what the first api call stored in the variable movies.

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const firstURL = https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=###&language=en-US&page=1


const firstCall = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(firsturl);
        const data = await response.json();
        setMovies([...movies, ...data.results]);
}

secondURL = https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=###&language=en-US&page=2

const secondCall = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(secondURL);
            const data = await response.json();
            setMovies([...movies, ...data.results]);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to use the spread operator if you want to over-write data. Simply do ```setMovies([data.results]);```

Comment: what you wrote seems like it would work fine.  what's the issue?

Comment: I don't want to override the data, I want the secondcall to append to the existing data from first api call in the state movies...Now this code only stores the first api call or sometime second and that's what display on the flatlist. I want both of this calls in the same state variable

Comment: Well, on second call of setMovies , just do this : setMovies(movies => movies.concat(data.results)), this will add the new data to the old ones

Comment: @CevaComic This worked for me. Please explain me what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: Got it, by reading the reading the use state react docs.